# Mother love or mother's love?

Tags: possessives

I found the following lines from a book written on philosophy:
"The love of a mother for her child is neither Buddhist nor Christian: it is mother love."
Is it possible to express "mother love" as it is? Shouldn't the word 'mother' be subjected to Possessive case and make it "mother's" love? Or is it just a proofing error?

Comment: It can be either.

Comment: Or again it can be _motherly love_.

Comment: It reminds me of the scifi thing: mother ship.

Comment: Since the writer opens with "The love of a mother" and then defines a new term *mother love*, that shows they are different. Other that that, the love of a mother directly equals mother's love.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this can be classified as an attempt at [solecism](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310214517/https://literarydevices.net/solecism), or, in a nutshell, intentionally mucking up grammatical conventions to make a point.  The view the author holds is that no religion or belief can claim to have influenced the love a mother has for her child... it's simply *mother* love.  The author is using "mother love" as a term to distinguish it from "Christian love" or "Buddhist love", because he or she believes that external claims to a mother's love for her child are erroneous.

Comment: Solecism? No, standard English. Look it up ([[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mother-love)])

Comment: It's intriguing that Collins has an entry under British English. I sourced four other dictionaries when writing this answer (cambridge, merriam-webster, macmillan, and dictionary.com) which all showed no results.

By comparison, a similarly British compound noun "car park" can be found in all four.  Do you hold that mother love should be considered "standard" English when it's absent from what appears to be a majority of dictionaries and when the "a mother's love" construction is historically more common?

Comment: FWIW, I'm quite familiar with the term 11 000 000 Ghits for << "mother love" -Queen >> is significant. Dr Brenda Hunter (a US citizen, I think) has written a book titled ['The Power of Mother Love'](https://www.focusonthefamily.com/parenting/the-power-of-a-mothers-love/) and uses the term in the book. There are many other examples. // But even 'British English' can still be standard, can't it? Lack of research, and lack of research shown, is what is non-standard on ELU.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I did not claim that British English was non-standard -- I pointed out that many sources do not list the term in their catalog alongside a different but similarly British term "car park".

Comment: Nice deflection. Do you still claim it's a solecism?

Answer (score 2):

> ...it is mother love." Is it possible to express "mother love" as it is?
>   Shouldn't the word 'mother' be subjected to Possessive case and make
>   it "mother's" love? Or is it just a proofing error?

It is *not* a mistake, actually it is the correct form:

the [Saxon genitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive), as you say, is  used to express the 'possevive case', that means that 'the person possesses something', in this case it would mean 'that **belongs to** a mother'.

In the case you quote the 'love' does not belong to the mother, but 'flows' from the mother to her child.

Therefore the form you consider correct is actually improper, "mother" here has the function of an adjective, corresponding and substituting "*maternal* love" = "love **relating/peculiar to** a mother"

Comment: But the genitive doesn't always indicate possession! In fact the word genitive itself indicates one of the other common senses: a source. If *'s* is a genitive then it would be entirely appropriate to use it if you are talking about a love that flows from the mother.

Comment: Where is your evidence that the 'saxon' genitive only indicates possession? Does it in "Ben's father"? Does it in "Rome's border"? Does it in "the river's course"?

Comment: 'Mother grandparent' can't be used for 'maternal grandparent'. 'Mother love' is an acknowledged compound noun.

Answer (score 1):

No, because "The love of a mother is a mother's love" is tautological, i.e. an empty assertion, while "The love of a mother is mother love" is not empty, so "a mother's love" and "mother love" can't mean the same.  (I supplied the "a" in "a mother's love, because without the "a", I find the sentence ungrammatical.)

Grammatically, "mother love" is noun, specifically a compound noun, composed of the two nouns "mother" and "love".  But "a mother's love" is a noun phrase (NP), and is equivalent to "the love of a mother".

One way to tell the difference is that "love" in the first cannot be modified by an adjective (because neither part of a noun-noun compound can be modified by an adjective), but "love" in the second can be.  *"mother eternal love" is ungrammatical, while "a mother's eternal love" is grammatical, and means "the eternal love of a mother".  ("eternal mother love" is simply the adjective "eternal" modifying the compound noun "mother love".)

Comment: But people say tautologies all the time. If the OP wants to say one, who are we to tell them not to?

Comment: @curiousdannii, well, not me.  I have nothing against saying tautologies.

Comment: Needs a reference. ([[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mother-love)])

Answer (score 1):

The traditional expression is "a mother's love".

The writer probably wrote "mother love" because English wasn't their first language, and they just decided to use "mother" to describe this unique and well-known form of love.

Since the meaning's clear, I'd let them off the hook and afford them a bit of creative license.

As for "mother" not being an adjective—well, of course it can be one, as in "the mother ship".

Comment: No. Look it up ([[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mother-love)])

Answer (score 0):

While this presentation of a type of love is nowhere near common, and you are correct that it would normally be presented as a possessive ("a mother's love"), it is not wrong.  The use of "mother" as a nominal adjective is certainly used regularly in other phrases ("a mother hen", "the mother Earth", "a mother tongue"), so to attempt to use "mother" to describe anything else is acceptable, even when it comes across as awkward to the ear.

"Mother", just for clarification, *is* an adjective by definition: "derived from or as if from one's mother" (Merriam-Webster).

Comment: "mother" is not an adjective.  A diagnostic for adjectives is that they can be modified by the adverb "very".  But *"a very mother hen", *"a very mother earth".  The examples you give are noun-noun compounds -- no adjectives.

Comment: Mother is an adjective and appears in numerous dictionaries under that description.  Your diagnostic is by no means comprehensive.

Comment: Instead of appealing to authority, how about giving us some evidence?  How do these numerous dictionary guys know that "mother" is an adjective?  "She is nice"/ *"She is mother"/ "She is a mother"/ *"She is a nice".  Nouns take articles; adjectives don't.

Comment: I did not say mother was not a noun (in fact, I first call it a nominal adjective, which is in fact a noun).  The word "mother" is both a noun and an adjective and can be used for both purposes.  An appeal to authority on subject matter is evidence, and I honestly don't know how to respond to your comment regarding Merriam-Webster as "dictionary guys" with seriousness.

Comment: What's the evidence that "mother" is an adjective?  If MW says it's an adjective, they must have some evidence that this is so, right? What's that evidence?

Comment: Dictionaries often conflate the concept of a "noun adjunct" into the concept of an "adjective", and describe noun adjuncts as adjectives. I think Cord's argument is unaffected (strengthened, even) if "nominal adjective" is replaced by "noun adjunct" in the first paragraph. So it's an issue of proper terminology, on which grammarians seem to be fighting a running battle with lexicographers.

Comment: One can't just put two likely candidates together and decide it's a compound noun. But one _can_ check in dictionaries, and 'mother love' is listed as a compound noun.  ([[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mother-love)])

Answer (score 0):

To define a possesive status as 2 ways :

1. A mother's love means the mother loves her child, 
    so this love belongs to her child.
2. The love of mother means the mother is loved by 
    her child, so this love belongs to the mother.

Comment: Look it up ([[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mother-love)])

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to interpret "mother love" in the original quote as meaning that it was almost a being in and of itself -- ie, "mother love" is analogous to "father time" or "old man winter" -- a personification, not so much possessed by mothers themselves (and hence not represented by the possessive "mother's) but (somewhat) separately existing in nature as a sort of deity.